# pip unusable in Python 3.12 virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.12

I've created a blank, brand-new Python project using PyCharm. From the command line, going into that project correctly activates the virtual environment.

```
$ [~/Developer] cd pythonProject
Switching pipenv: pythonProject-IbA-tQW [Python 3.12.0]

$ [~/Developer/pythonProject]
```

In that virtual environment, `python` and `pipenv` both work:

```
$ [~/Developer/pythonProject] python --version
Python 3.12.0

$ [~/Developer/pythonProject] pipenv --version
pipenv, version 2022.6.7

$ [~/Developer/pythonProject]
```

However, `pip` refuses to run, which makes it impossible to install packages.

```
$ [~/Developer/pythonProject] pip install icecream
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andrew/.local/share/virtualenvs/pythonProject-IbA-tQW-/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  ...
  File "/Users/andrew/.local/share/virtualenvs/pythonProject-IbA-tQW-/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/_distutils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils.cmd import Command as DistutilsCommand
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

$ [~/Developer/pythonProject]
```

Maybe it's picking up the wrong `pip`. Let's see what version it is…

```
$ [~/Developer/pythonProject] pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andrew/.local/share/virtualenvs/pythonProject-IbA-tQW-/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  ...
  File "/Users/andrew/.local/share/virtualenvs/pythonProject-IbA-tQW-/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/_distutils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils.cmd import Command as DistutilsCommand
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

$ [~/Developer/pythonProject]
```

So I'm not actually trying to do anything with `pip` — just see what version it is. Apparently I can't do that.

Outside the virtual environment, it's fine:

```
$ [~/Developer] pip --version
pip 23.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)

$ [~/Developer]
```

I'm really starting to be quite bothered by the difficulty in Python virtual environments. It's a bit of a trainwreck, to be honest. Every time I need to upgrade a Python version it's a major issue.

What do I have to do to install a package in a Python 3.12 virtual environment when `pip` refuses to work?

---

Edit: Poetry doesn't help, as it defers to `pip` for package removal. Partial poetry output:

```
The following error occurred when trying to handle this error:


  EnvCommandError

  Command ['/Users/andrew/.local/share/virtualenvs/pythonProject-IbA-tQW-/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'uninstall', 'icecream', '-y'] errored with the following return code 1

  Output:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    ...
    File "/Users/andrew/.local/share/virtualenvs/pythonProject-IbA-tQW-/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/_distutils.py", line 9, in <module>
      from distutils.cmd import Command as DistutilsCommand
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
```

Comment: poetry can be a good "alternative" to pip (even if poetry uses pip). You can definitely try it

Comment: poetry works to add packages, but it can't remove them — same problem, as its removal is a veneer over pip.

Comment: I had the same problem until I updated PyCharm to the latest version. I have a pro license but I don't think that matters. Try updating and recreate your venv.